# CreateProcess Api creating two instances of application

Tags: win32-process

I have a *watchdog* application, it monitors whether my main application is running or not, if it's not running watchdog is responsible for starting the main application, using `CreateProcess` api.

Sometimes the main application is getting launched twice. I have ensured only a single instance of application exists at any time, using a mutex. *Watchdog* does the monitoring on timer basis. The timer is set to 3 seconds. Do not understand why second instance of application is getting launched.

Comment: Without seeing your actual code, the only way I could imagine this happening is if there is a bug in the watchdog where it is not detecting an existing instance properly and decides to launch a new instance when it should not be.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your help, I saw a strange behavior, my main application was launching itself. I checked this through wmic command displaying parentprocessid and processid. When I had a look at EventViewer.msc, the exception code was 0xc0000374. I will update more.

Comment: Hi Remy, I have solved the problem, there was a heap corruption problem. This triggered Microsoft Error reporting service, causing my application to go into suspended state, which made watchdog to think it is running.

Comment: If you save the `hProcess` returned in `CreateProcess`, you only need to execute `GetExitCodeProcess` for this handle (for example in a loop). If the `dwCode`, obtained in `GetExitCodeProcess` is different to `STILL_ACTIVE`, you need to restart it because it is stop.